# What does the Apple HealthKit guideline mean here?

Tags: ios, app-store, healthkit

if anybody has been able to get their health kit app approved by Apple, I would really appreciate your help. I am confused as to exactly how I would be able to "identify the HealthKit functionality in the app’s user interface" as is stated in the health kit guidelines.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was creating a view that the user could navigate to prior to authorizing HealthKit data access. The view was a simple bullet point list of text explaining what the app was doing with each of the health data types it was asking them to share.
I was able to send the app reviewer a screenshot of this view of text right there in the iTunes Connect portal to get their thumbs up before actually resubmitting the app for the week-long approval process.

Additionally, if you're looking to store user HealthKit data on 3rd party servers you are going to need to communicate this with the user before asking them for authorization to HealthKit data. Your app will be rejected otherwise. Again, a simple label bluntly stating that the app would be storing the user's HealthKit data on 3rd party servers was all that was needed for me to get my app approved.